# Retrieve and display last entry indatabase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

Frank  · 2 hours ago

Using Ionic 2, I am unsuccessfully trying to retrieve and display the newGoalWt, newMaxReps, newMinReps, repsToday, and wtToday shown at the bottom of the firebase data image. I do not want to retrieve the other data.  I thought I found the answer to this several times, but I haven't.  I am not trying to get others to do work I should be doing but I am new to coding and need help at this point. If you have another course that covers this by example please let me know.  [sample database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GARcY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this makes sense/is clear.

First thing is to create a provider which gets the details. So in the provider there will be a function like this :

```
public getRequiredObject(objectKey : String){
   return this.database.object('wideGripBPTwo-list/'+ objectKey)
}
```

Then in the controller/typescript file i would have a variable assigned to the return value of the provider :

```
this.variableName = this.Provider.getRequiredObject(objectKey);
this.variableName.subscribe(snapshot => {
  this.newGoalWt = snapshot.newGoalWt;
  this.newMaxReps = snapshot.newMaxReps;
  //add other variables here
```

Lastly in the html file just bind the data :

```
  <ion-label>{{newGoalWt}}</ion-label>
```

Note I have not added entire provider, .ts file and html file.
Please advise if this makes sense and if you need more assistance.